# How do ROS nodes in microcontrollers work?

Tags: ros, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a general question.

As far as I know, when a microcontroller is powered, it automatically runs its main program. So when a ROS node is implemented in a microcontroller, e.g. arduino, it runs the node even when it is not connected to any ROS master/connected to a PC (at least that's how I understand it).

My question is how does the ROS master discovery mechanism work on the microcontroller? Or in which file of the `rosserial` library is it implemented?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345813/how-do-ros-nodes-in-microcontrollers-work?/) by [didi1311](https://answers.ros.org/users/52228/didi1311/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosserial` is a protocol for wrapping standard ROS serialized messages and multiplexing multiple topics and services over a character device such as a serial port or network socket. It has **Client libraries** that allow users to easily get ROS nodes up and running on various systems. And it also has **ROS-side Interfaces** allows you setup a node on the host machine to bridge the connection from the serial protocol to the more general ROS network. It's not ROS master discovery mechanism works between the host machine and the microcontroller. When you write your own project on microcontroller, you will depend on `rosserial` 's client libraries. If you just work on a host machine with a non-ROS microcontroller, you have to write a package which is able to connect with the device.

---

Originally posted by [vaspo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38387/vaspo/) with karma: 61 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2